# Difference Between ItemEvent.getStateChange() and checkbox.getState() when using it on ItemListener?

Tags: java, itemlistener

So I'm new to Java and I'm trying to make a simple text editor as my 1st java program. so I'm currently working on text wrapping. so Originally my code looks like this.

```
public class WordWrapListener implements ItemListener {
    public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent e) {
        if(wrapMenuItem.getState() == true) { // I changed this line of code
            editorTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
            editorTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            frame.repaint();
        } else {
            editorTextArea.setLineWrap(false);
            editorTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(false);
            frame.repaint();
        }
```

now the code above does not work. so I googled how to make an ItemsListener and found the answer below:

```
public class WordWrapListener implements ItemListener {
    public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent e) {
        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) { // I changed this line
            editorTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
            editorTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            frame.repaint();
        } else {
            editorTextArea.setLineWrap(false);
            editorTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(false);
            frame.repaint();
        }
    }
} // end inner class
```

I'm a little confused as to why my original code does not work? I just want to get a better understanding on this cause based on my understanding those two are pretty much the same the only difference is that getState() is method from checkbox that output true/false and getStateChange() is from ItemEvent that output SELECTED/DESELECTED?

If that so is there a way to make my 1st code working? like using getState() == true??

EDIT:

here's the snippet of the code that uses the listener. so I declared my JTextArea as an Instance variable.

```
private void go() {
    // make frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("DVTextEditor");

    //make menu bar and menu
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    JMenu formatMenu = new JMenu("Format");

    //make menu items for file menu
    JMenuItem newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New");
    JMenuItem openMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
    JMenuItem saveMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Save");

    //add menu items in file menu
    fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);
    fileMenu.add(openMenuItem);
    fileMenu.add(saveMenuItem);

    //action listeners for New and Save menu items
    newMenuItem.addActionListener(new NewMenuListener());
    openMenuItem.addActionListener(new OpenMenuListener());
    saveMenuItem.addActionListener(new SaveMenuListener());

    //make menu items for format menu
    JCheckBoxMenuItem wrapMenuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Word Wrap ");

    //add menu items in format menu
    formatMenu.add(wrapMenuItem);

    //action listener for word Wrap item menu
    wrapMenuItem.addItemListener(new WordWrapListener());  // <------------------------------

    // add menu in menu bar
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
    menuBar.add(formatMenu);

    // meke text area and put inside scrollpane
    editorTextArea = new JTextArea(15, 50);
    JScrollPane eScrollBar = new JScrollPane(editorTextArea);
    eScrollBar.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    eScrollBar.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    // add menu bar and text area in frame
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, eScrollBar);

    // enable frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Thank you,

Comment: Both code fragments should have same behavior, unless listener is added to the wrong component. Could you provide a snippet of the code, that uses `WordWrapListener`?

Comment: Hi kgeorgiy, thanks for your response, I edited my post to show the full snippet that uses WordWrapListener, so basically I added my listener to the JCheckboxMenuItem.

Comment: so I tried to changed my code back to my original plan and now it's working.. so both code are now working, seems like I added the Listener on the different component like you thought!!

Answer (score 0):

so turns out I added the Listener to a wrong component like kgeorgiy suspected.
I tried running both code with the listener added to wrapMenuItem.addItemListener(new WordWrapListener());

both codes are now working although I prefer to use the latter since with this one I don't have to declare the wrapMenuItem as an Instance Variable.